# Magento success page redirect to store url

Tags: magento, redirect

My current success page in `magento` is redirected to base url:

`mainsite/checkout/onepage/success/`

I need to redirect it on store url via:

`mainsite/websitecode/storecode/onepage/success/`

Let me know how to redirect it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_redirectUrl()` method.

Comment: Hi Chankey, thanks for your response but how to redirect it into [link](websitecode/storecode/onepage/success). As I dig in on the codes ,found onepagecontroller on successaction :                      $this->_redirect('checkout/cart'); how should I change it?

Answer (score 0):

I able to solve these issue with Chankey's hint. I change the redirectURL on my Controller file under response action:
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('websitecode/storecode/checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));

It works!